# Error:Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-rc-3-all.zip

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I changed my **Gradle** version to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'
```

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'
```

and started getting this error. I tried to clean and rebuild the project but it didn't work. Reverting back to alpha05 version is not working anymore.

appearently the problem is in my **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-rc-3-all.zip
```

Comment: Latest Gradle is 4.4.1, make it `gradle-4.4.1-all.zip` and try again.

Answer (score 11):

This answer will not solve the OP's problem, but I had exactly the same error, Google gave this SO URL, and my solution was slightly different

I replaced the `http` with `https` (note the 's') in the `gradle.properties` file.

Since others may find this SO question with a Google search, I am posting my answer here.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using gradle-wrapper, navigate to your project folder and delete the gradle subfolder then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 5):

The endpoint is no longer available over HTTP, change it to HTTPS.

Change the distributionUrl in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to `https\://...`.

Answer (score 4):

> The [**`Gradle Wrapper`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) can download Gradle distributions from servers
>   using HTTP Basic Authentication. This enables you to host the Gradle
>   distribution on a private protected server. You can specify a username
>   and password in two different ways depending on your use case: as
>   system properties or directly embedded in the distributionUrl.
>   Credentials in system properties take precedence over the ones
>   embedded in distributionUrl.

Kindly check list [**`distributionUrl`**](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/).

You should use latest version, i.e

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 2):

Manually download the gradle-4.4.1-all.zip file and paste it in the below path

"C:\Users\XXX.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\"

And finally click **Try again** in the Android Studio, it will start the syncing process.

Answer (score 0):

Changing distributionUrl manually to the latest version didn't work.

So I removed the gradle wrapper and regenerate it, gave me this url

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-4.4-20171031235950+0000-all.zip
```